# Why does the type-inferencing logic fails with an iteration over a TreeNodeCollection?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, type-inference, c#-5.0

I am a bit puzzled with this behavior,

This code compiles fine:

```
private void CheckAvailabilityOfCurrentTreeNodes() {
   foreach( TreeNode treeNode in this.DeviceTree.Nodes ) {
      if( Object.ReferenceEquals(treeNode.Tag, _recorder.CaptureDevice) ) {
         ...     
       }
   }
}
```

But the following produces a compilation error saying that `'object' does not contain a definition for 'Tag'`

```
private void CheckAvailabilityOfCurrentTreeNodes() {
   foreach( var treeNode in this.DeviceTree.Nodes ) {
      if( Object.ReferenceEquals(treeNode.Tag, _recorder.CaptureDevice) ) {
         ...     
       }
   }
}
```

In this case, the type-inferencing logic is returning `Object` as the iterator's result type, but I don't understand clearly why, since the `TreeNodeCollection` is strongly-typed.  Is it because this collection type is quite dated?

**Can someone enlighten me on the technical reasons for this behavior?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> since the `TreeNodeCollection` is strongly-typed

Here is the definition of the [`TreeNodeCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
public class TreeNodeCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

As you can see, it's *not* strongly typed because it implements the non generic `IEnumerable` interface rather than `IEnumerable<TreeNode>`. So the type inference works, just the inferred type from `IEnumerable.Current` is `object`.

This basically applies to all WinForms collections. Although most of them provide strongly typed indexer, all they implement the non generic `IEnumerable` interface.

Why? Because they were created at the time generics (hence `IEnumerable<T>` interface) didn't exist. And simply never get updated.

Comment: Indeed, the strongly-typed 'facade' of the collection made me believe it was somehow strongly-typed. Thanks for the insight!